# Using DateDiff to find examples where table_1.column A and table_2.column B have <90 mins difference

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-difference

I am trying to find a way to filter records where the difference in two date/time fields is less than 90 minutes.

Example:

```
orders.created_at = 2015-08-09 20:30:20
table2.created_at = 2015-08-09 20:09:30
```

I have tried using TimeDiff, although I don't understand how the syntax would apply to this example.

Data comes from separate tables both linking to the same order information. The aim is to find examples of where an order has been placed within 90 minutes, but a third field has not been updated. I would be using an `AND` query for only including results where a third field is `NULL`

Comment: Please show the data from the two tables and the desired results.  It is entirely unclear what the tables have to do with each other.

Comment: thanks - I've added further information. In short, I'm trying to pull up records based on two tables within our database. Where the difference between the times is less than 90 minutes, and other queries result in a NULL result, the outcome would show an issue with some of our code. The difference would displayed in the output table as difference, e.g. `DATEDIFF as difference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql, you need to use TIMEDIFF() or UNIX_TIMESTAMP for this. I prefer the UNIX_TIMESTAMP solution because it's simpler:

```
WHERE
thirdfield IS NULL
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.created_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table2.created_at) < 5400
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE
thirdfield IS NULL
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.created_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table2.created_at) < 5400
```

Does that work both ways, or do you have to expand to "(A-B < 5400 AND A-B >0) OR (B-A <5400 AND B-A > 0)"?

```
((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.created_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table2.created_at) < 5400) 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.created_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table2.created_at) > 0)) 
OR ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table2.created_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.created_at) < 5400) 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table2.created_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.created_at) > 0))
```